# making a "pitch" unavailable, for specific dates,

Tags: database, web

Not sure where to put this, but its just a general question for some help as i am stuck.  I have been tasked to design a booking database, for a campsite, one of the requirements is that is should be possible to mark one of the pitches unavailable for a 24 hr period, the only way i can think of doing this is with a bit data type, and when a booking is done the sql will check if the bit is set and if it is then the pitch is unavailable. this is fine for marking it not available from the day you set it, but i am wondering if there is a way to do is so you could forward date it so it wasn't available on a certain date/dates then booking could still be made on that pitch but just not during the desired dates. any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just defining a boolean column in the pitches table can indeed be inadequate :

- if we want to define an unavailability period in the future
- if we want to know when a pitch was unavailable
- and dont forget that you'll have to change the boolean value after 24 hours.

If you dont need to manage unavailability periods in the future or track old periods, you can define a nullable date column which will contain the next availability date. So when a pitch starts to be unavailable, it will take the current date + 24 hours. So the available pitches have a NULL date or a date < to the current date.

Otherwise, I think you should define a table containing the pitch id, the start date and end date of unavailability.

Comment: i like the start and end date on the pitch table idea. so when a list of available pitches are made for a certain time period it first checks to see if it is in the booking table during those times and the if the start and end date of the booking is within the start/end date of the pitch table, would this work if there is null values in the pitch table,

Comment: If I well understand the idea, yes, I think it will work if there are NULL dates : a pitch will be available for a date if the date is not between dates or if dates are NULL

Comment: Brill, this has worked perfectly, i has just added the two start and end columns to my pitch table and two more lines to my query to see if the dates are not between start/end or the values are null and it returned all that are available, this has worked great

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something you want to handle in the application layer rather than the database layer.

In your database design you will have a `site` table and a `booking` table. the `booking` table will key to `site` and have a start and end datetime. When you create a new booking for a site, check that it does not fall in the range for any other booking the site.